# Eventbrite: How do I change the start date of an existing repeating event

Tags: events, repeat, eventbrite

We have a repeating event set up and have done several of the events already.  Now we need to change the start date and end date of the event (because we want to not hold the event for a couple of weeks).  Eventbrite is allowing us to change the end date of the repeating event, but not the start date.  I can select a different start date, but when I save the event the change to the start date reverts back to the previous date we had selected.

Any idea what could cause this?  Any idea of a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the start date is in the past, and if the event has had attendees, you cannot change its start date.  Instead, change the end date to the date of the last recurring event in the series and create a new recurring event.  The old event can be cloned to ensure the two events are identical (with the exception of the start and end dates of course).